# if condition for huge amount of object properties

Tags: php, object

I have to show the record from database if at least one filed is filled with value out of 50 fields for a row.

I fetched data from database successfully. Stored in array of object like this

```
$obj[0]->prop1;
$obj[0]->prop2;

$obj[1]->prop1;
$obj[1]->prop2;
```

There are more than 50 properties for a object.

I have to check each property if one of them is not empty show that record.

I have a long if like this

```
if ($obj[$counter]->prop1 !='' || $obj[0]->prop2 !='' ...
echo "show record"
```

wanted to know if there is shorten way. let me know if anything is not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a function `isEmpty()` in the class. For each instance, you will have to only call

```
if(!($obj[$counter]->isEmpty()) {

   ...

}
```

Comment: it is an object of stdClass and created using mysql_fetch_object so I can not create method

Comment: @Daric: You can pass a classname to `mysql_fetch_object()`, thus you _can_ create a method. http://php.net/mysql-fetch-object

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's better to alter your query:

`select f1, f2, ... f50, f1||f2...||f50 as fsum from ...`

and then you can check if `$obj[51] != ''`

this will perform faster than `php` code...

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to check each property individually...

Answer (score 0):

So I found the easy way myself. You can just do a type cast the object to an array and check that array for values like this

```
foreach ((array)$data[$counter] as $value)
{
   if($value !='')
   {
      $addRec=true;
   }
}
```